# How to have pushViewController show only destination view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, storyboard, pushviewcontroller

I have a login UIViewController that handles authentication.

If a user exists, I push a main view to the UI.

This works fine, but it first shows the login window for a second before doing the slide animation.  I would like the main view to show only if the user exists so it doesn't look like it is unnecessarily sliding past the login view controller.

I do the push with the following:

```
MainViewController *mvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"main"];
 [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
```

How can I skip straight to the main view controller?

Comment: animated:no is your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting the `animated` Boolean to `NO` will show the view controller immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Change animated parameter to NO:  `animated:NO`